# Angular 7 and sass/scss - Module build failed

Tags: css, angular, sass

I created new project with Angular 7. I decided to use scss, but I have compilation error.

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

      undefined
^
  Invalid CSS after "h1": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
  in C:\Users\bartek\...\...\sassTest\scssy-project\src\styles.scss (line 4, column 3)
```

I used this command to create new project:

```
 ng new scssy-project --style=scss
```

I was trying rebuild node-sass, but without any result. I see that this problem appears in few topics. But I can't found solution for my problem.

[Here is my repo](https://bitbucket.org/kudlaty9102/sass-error/src/master/)

Comment: delete node-sass from your root node folder , and reinstall it.

Comment: @Yoarthur I do this, few times on few project. It's doesn't work

Comment: what does it said?. Please use https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Problem solved. Today everything works correct.

Comment: What did you do?.

Comment: I am not sure, but probably use scss syntax in sass file. But now everything works.